# Can someone "have a moment of reprieve"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I'm editing a friend's essay for graduate school. They use the sentence:

> "I want to help patients have a moment of reprieve."

It feels odd to me, but I don't want to make an edit if it's not grammatically incorrect or misuses the word. Any input would be helpful - thank you!

Comment: It seems right to me. And if you look for the phrase on [google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22have+a+moment+of+reprieve%22), it's clearly used by others as well. It seems to be gaining popularity if you look on [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+moment+of+reprieve&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), but I can't really think of a good phrase to compare it with.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the phrase is odd, you could just flag it and ask your friend to decide for themselves whether to change it or not.

I don't believe it is grammatically incorrect, or a misuse of the word. Despite Mark's claims "[reprieve](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reprieve)" has been used as a noun for centuries. In fact its first recorded use is as a noun (in 1552), predating its first recorded use as verb (in 1596) by 44 years.

It's recorded use in the meaning of "*a temporary respite (as from pain or trouble)*" also fits this situation.

However, note that this is just an observation about its historic use, and not a judgment on whether or not it *should* be used as a noun, or whether its use in this phrase is or isn't *horrid*. Dictionaries are descriptive, not prescriptive.

If we [compare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+moment+of+reprieve%2C+have+a+moment+of+respite%2Chave+a+moment+of+relief&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) this phrase with alternatives using "respite" or "relief", you can see that both of those are more commonly used, but not to an overwhelming extent.

[image]

You could further have a browse through examples on google books to look in more detail at how this phrase and alternatives are used
(links: [reprieve](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+moment+of+reprieve%22&tbm=bks),
[respite](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+moment+of+respite%22&tbm=bks),
[relief](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+moment+of+relief%22&tbm=bks))

"It feels odd to me" or "it's a horrid expression" *are* valid reasons to flag it to your friend as something to consider changing, even if it does appear to be in common usage. In the end, the only thing that really matters is the intended audience. If it's something that the readers will find odd or dislike, then finding a more palatable alternative is the right choice, but honestly, I don't think most people would blink at it.

Comment: 'Respite' works best for me. Reprieve can be used accurately, but I'd associate it more with 'spared punishment' than 'from pain'.

Answer (score 0):

I thought initially that it was OK, but then realised I was getting 'reprieve' mixed up with 'respite'. I'd say either 'a moment of respite' or 'a reprieve', although I'd probably only use the latter if the patient had a terminal illness and unexpectedly had a period of remission.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly natural and grammatically acceptable. Reprieve is a verb, but it's more commonly used as a noun. In fact, replacing it with "break" or "rest" is pretty effective at showing this, as they too can be used as nouns or verbs. I don't think anyone would argue that "a moment of rest" is incorrect. This isn't a foolproof tactic to determine the validity of a phrase, but it can be a useful test.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's a horrid expression.  *reprieve* is a verb and you really need a noun in that position in that sentence.  Perhaps use *respite* or *relief*.

Comment: It's also a noun according to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reprieve (and other dictionaries I looked at). Meaning 3 seems to fit perfectly: "a temporary respite (as from pain or trouble)"

Comment: I don't care what Merriam Webster say, it's a horrid expression.  But I don't seem to have had a huge number of people piling in to support my disgust :-(

Comment: If it's any comfort, [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+moment+of+reprieve%2C+have+a+moment+of+respite%2Chave+a+moment+of+relief&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) does suggest both `respite` and `relief` _are_ more commonly used in this context.